# Word for "personal data-point"?

Tags: word-request

When you want to say you don't have a lot of data but have a personal data point, just one story, but that could be useful - what's the word for that?

There is a famous quote by Jeff Bezos where he says he pays attention to emails sent directly to him because they serve as `...`. Often if the data doesn't agree with that one piece of `...`, the data is wrong.

The term can also be used in a negative way - "this isn't reliable statistical data, it's just `...`".

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on a quotation that is reasonably easy to find: ["The thing I have noticed is when the anecdotes and the data disagree, the anecdotes are usually right. There's something wrong with the way you are measuring it," he explained.](https://www.businessinsider.com/bezos-explains-his-dreaded-one-character-emails-2018-4) (Business Insider)

Comment: It's not easy to find if you don't know the word "anecdote". I searched for [jeff bezos quote data wrong], [jeff bezos famous quotes].

I'm disappointed to be voted-down. Isn't this community for English learners? Isn't this tag used for this exact purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for *anecdotal evidence*:

> Anecdotal evidence is evidence from anecdotes, i.e., evidence collected in a casual or informal manner and relying heavily or entirely on personal testimony.
>
> Where only one or a few anecdotes are presented, there is a larger chance that they may be unreliable due to cherry-picked or otherwise non-representative samples of typical cases. Similarly, psychologists have found that due to cognitive bias people are more likely to remember notable or unusual examples rather than typical examples. Thus, even when accurate, anecdotal evidence is not necessarily representative of a typical experience. Accurate determination of whether an anecdote is typical requires statistical evidence. Misuse of anecdotal evidence is an informal fallacy and is sometimes referred to as the "person who" fallacy ("I know a person who..."; "I know of a case where..." etc.) which places undue weight on experiences of close peers which may not be typical.

<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence))</sub>

This term is indeed often used in a negative way.